# HiveServer2 is giving ConnectionRefused error?

Tags: hadoop, hive

In my applications I am using HiveServer2 url to connect to the hive for querying hive table(tables are HbaseStorageHandler  tables).Initially application is working properly for sometime,after 2 or 3 hours application is giving exception as ConnectionRefused. If I restart the hive services, again sometime application will work fine.This process is repeating.So i am not able to find the cause.Anybody know the cause or solution please share me how to resolve this issue.

these are in the hive log:

```
CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
 supervisord started with pid 4593
 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
 INFO supervisord started with pid 4593
 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 4731
 INFO spawned: 'hive' with pid 4732
 INFO spawned: 'hive2' with pid 4733
 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 127; not expected)
 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 4909
 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 127; not expected)
 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 4928
 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 127; not expected)
 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 4956
 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 127; not expected)
 INFO success: hive entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 10 seconds (startsecs)
 INFO success: hive2 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 10 seconds (startsecs)
 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 4966
 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 127; not expected)
 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 4978
 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 127; not expected)
 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 5008
 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 127; not expected)
 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 5025
 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 127; not expected)
 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 5038
 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 127; not expected)
 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 5072
 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 127; not expected)
```

but in application log it is giving as:

```
Exception in DB Connection java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://10.76.1.181:10000/: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Sat Mar 04 17:50:42 IST 2017 : Exception in DB Connection java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://10.76.1.181:10000/: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Sat Mar 04 17:50:42 IST 2017 : Exception in DB Connection java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://10.76.1.181:10000/: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Sat Mar 04 17:50:42 IST 2017 : Exception in DB Connection java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://10.76.1.181:10000/: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Sat Mar 04 17:50:42 IST 2017 : Exception in DB Connection java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://10.76.1.181:10000/: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Sat Mar 04 17:50:42 IST 2017 : Exception in DB Connection java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://10.76.1.181:10000/: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Comment: Share hive logs so that it can be helpful to find the issue.

Comment: Sat Mar 04 17:50:42 IST 2017 : Exception in DB Connection java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://10.76.1.181:10000/: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)                                        same thing is repeating.But if i am checking hive service status,it is showing as running.

Comment: I added my log in the question,please go through the edits.